# vscode always show "Error: The request timed out." on the top

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: The Screen shot]

The vscode editor always show "Error: The request timed out'(see Screen shot above) every few minutes.
why?

Comment: Pls read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Before posting a query